# How to run jetty with https using sbt 0.7.7

Tags: scala, https, jetty, sbt

I am using jetty 2.1.6 and sbt 0.7.7.

Currently my app is running on http, but I want to run with https

I tried following approach to run it with https :
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_SSL#Configuring_Jetty_for_SSL

Then i set below code in build.scala file.

```
     override lazy val jettyInstance = new JettyRunner(customJettyConfiguration)
  def customJettyConfiguration = {
    val myLog = log
    val myJettyClasspath = jettyClasspath
    new CustomJettyConfiguration {
      def war = "target/scala_2.8.0/tos.war"
      def scanDirectories = Nil
      def scanInterval = 0
      def jettyClasspath = myJettyClasspath
      def classpath = jettyRunClasspath
      def classpathName = "test"
      def log = myLog
      override def jettyConfigurationXML =
        <Configure id="Server" class="org.mortbay.jetty.Server">
          <Call name="addConnector">
            <Arg>
              <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.security.SslSocketConnector">
                <Set name="Port">443</Set>
                <Set name="maxIdleTime">30000</Set>
                <Set name="handshakeTimeout">2000</Set>
                <Set name="keystore"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default=""/>/etc/xinetd.d/keystore</Set>
                <Set name="password">password</Set>
                <Set name="keyPassword">password</Set>
                <Set name="truststore"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default=""/>/etc/xinetd.d/keystore</Set>
                <Set name="trustPassword">password</Set>
                <Set name="handshakeTimeout">2000</Set>
              </New>
            </Arg>
          </Call>
          <Call name="addConnector">
            <Arg>
              <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                <Set name="host"><SystemProperty name="jetty.host"/></Set>
                <Set name="port"><SystemProperty name="jetty.port" default="8080"/></Set>
                <Set name="maxIdleTime">30000</Set>
                <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
                <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
                <Set name="confidentialPort">443</Set>
                <Set name="lowResourcesConnections">5000</Set>
                <Set name="lowResourcesMaxIdleTime">5000</Set>
              </New>
            </Arg>
          </Call>
        </Configure>
    }
  }
```

But I did not get my work done.

Please let me know , if i am doing anything wrong.

**EDIT**

```
I am using 6.1.26 version of jetty.
```

Sorry, i mentioned it wrong earlier.

**EDIT**

Now I have successfully upgraded my jetty server to jetty-8.0.0.M3

Now i am getting below error when I am writing above code in my build.scala file :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
at sbt.jetty.LazyJettyRun7$$anonfun$3.apply(LazyJettyRun7.scala:96)
at sbt.jetty.LazyJettyRun7$$anonfun$3.apply(LazyJettyRun7.scala:95)
at scala.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:414)
at scala.List$$anon$2.foreach(List.scala:598)
at scala.Iterable$class.foreach(Iterable.scala:256)
at scala.xml.NodeSeq.foreach(NodeSeq.scala:34)
at sbt.jetty.LazyJettyRun7$.apply(LazyJettyRun7.scala:95)
at sbt.JettyRunner.runJetty$1(WebApp.scala:49)
at sbt.JettyRunner.apply(WebApp.scala:58)
at sbt.WebScalaProject$$anonfun$jettyRunTask$1.apply(ScalaProject.scala:383)
at sbt.WebScalaProject$$anonfun$jettyRunTask$1.apply(ScalaProject.scala:383)
at sbt.TaskManager$Task.invoke(TaskManager.scala:62)
at sbt.impl.RunTask.doRun$1(RunTask.scala:77)
at sbt.impl.RunTask.runTask(RunTask.scala:85)
at sbt.impl.RunTask.run(RunTask.scala:32)
at sbt.impl.RunTask$.apply(RunTask.scala:17)
at sbt.impl.RunTask$.apply(RunTask.scala:16)
at sbt.Project$class.run(Project.scala:98)
at sbt.Project$class.act(Project.scala:129)
at sbt.BasicScalaProject.act(DefaultProject.scala:21)
at sbt.xMain$$anonfun$8.apply(Main.scala:530)
at sbt.xMain$$anonfun$8.apply(Main.scala:530)
at sbt.xMain.withAction(Main.scala:563)
at sbt.xMain.sbt$xMain$$handleAction(Main.scala:530)
at sbt.xMain.handleCommand(Main.scala:520)
at sbt.xMain.processAction(Main.scala:459)
at sbt.xMain.process$1(Main.scala:257)
at sbt.xMain$Continue$1.apply(Main.scala:132)
at sbt.xMain.run$1(Main.scala:136)
at sbt.xMain.processArguments(Main.scala:266)
at sbt.xMain.startProject(Main.scala:107)
at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:84)
at sbt.xMain.run0$1(Main.scala:35)
at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:42)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:55)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:69)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:31)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
```

[info] == jetty-run ==
[error] Error running jetty-run: Error running Jetty: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(Ljava/lang/Object;)V

Comment: You know that there exists Jetty 9 and sbt 0.13? And the link you showed is for Jetty 7 and 8.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that in the `SelectChannelConnector` you have `confidentialPort` as `8443`, but in `SslSocketConnector` you have the  port as `443`. Are these supposed to match? What port are you specifying when hitting a `https` URL?

Comment: Jetty 2.6.1 is so ancient that even the Jetty developers have lost any and all copies of it.  You have class references to `org.mortbay.jetty` which is for Jetty versions 5.x and 6.x, you should use `org.eclipse.jetty` if you are using Jetty 7.x, 8.x, or 9.x

Comment: Some Jetty history. There was never a Jetty 2.6.1. SSL was added at Jetty 2.3.5 (Jan 2000) as a kiwiconsulting contrib. Jetty 2.4.6 (Aug 2000) included some OpenSSL support for SSL. Jetty 3.0.0 (Dec 2000) was the first with fully integrated SSL.

Comment: @theon I want to hit on default port that is 443

Comment: I am using 6.1.26. version of sbt and that is also older., But i can't update that for now, so I need solution only for this version

Comment: @sschaef I have made both port same as 443.

Answer (score 2):

`0.7.7` is a a pretty old version of SBT. I understand you may have reasons not to upgrade, but if you can there is the [xsbt-web-plugin](https://github.com/JamesEarlDouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/) SBT plugin that makes [configuring SSL](https://github.com/JamesEarlDouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/wiki/Settings) in Jetty super easy.

Comment: Ya, you are correct that i can't upgrade that but I need solution only for this version. So please provide me solution for this version of jetty